# Telegram Web inconsistency: showing as "read" a message sent yesterday but also showing "last seen over a week ago". How is it possible?

Tags: telegram

Yesterday i sent a message to one of my contacts, after a few hours the message showed the double check, so it was marked as read, but the last access was still over a week ago. Does anyone know how is it possible? I tried to browse the web and i found out that Telegram Web sometimes screws up with the "Last seen" feature, so maybe that's the issue, does anyone know more about it?

I already did some experiments:

- tapping "Mark as read" on the telegram notification also changes your status to online;
- turning on airplane mode / disabling Wi-Fi before reading the message does not show the message as read until Telegram is opened again with an internet connection, so this also affect the online status.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when the user has **changed his show `Last seen & online` settings**. It is a privacy setting, and one may hide his/her last seen status from everyone or selectively from some people.